# getting a weird jquery error that i cant figure it out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run event when the user enters an amount and im getting this error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="ItemQuantity#i#" name="ItemQuantity#i#" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)" onkeydown="return keyispressed(event);" onchange="autototal()">
```

trying to focus on the onchange="autototal()"

JQuery

```
function autototal(){
  var sum = 0;
  var quantity = 0;
  var price = 0;
  var totalPrice = 0;
  quantity = $(this).val();
  price = $(this).closest('.col-price').find('input').val();

  console.log(quantity);
  console.log(price); 
}
```

Comment: You aren't using `toLowerCase` anywhere in your code...

Comment: is that all your code?

Comment: yes that pertains to this error, right makes no sense

Comment: @AndrewL.: The OP isn't, no, but jQuery does under the covers when dealing with `$(this).val()` when `this` refers to `window`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're calling your handler, `this` isn't the element, it's `window`.

Either use jQuery to hook up the handler, which will ensure that `this` refers to the element:

```js
$("[id='ItemQuantity#i#']").on("change", autototal);
```

...or if you really want to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handling, either do this:

```js
<input ... onchange="autototal.call(this)">
```

and it should work as is, or do this:

```
onchange="autototal(this)"
```

...and update `autototal` to use the argument rather than `this`.

Comment: this part throws an error `elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()` inside jQuery, where `elem` refers to `window` because of the reasons you mentioned

Comment: @Maximus: With the OP's code, yes; not with the code above.